# Angular - link two API sources in table based on ID FK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, foreign-keys, ngresource

I'm really new to Angular and i'm trying to create a list of user transactions that presents the time of the action and the user's name.  In my audit API I have an action ID and the User FK which associates with my User API and i'm displaying it as follows:

```
HTML
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>                
            <th>
                Date/Time
            </th>
            <th>
                User
            </th>                
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>           
        <tr ng-repeat="audit in audit.data>
            <td>{{audit.audit_date_time}}</td>
            <td>**{{audit.audit_user_fk}}**</td>   **<--I need the name not the ID here**             
        </tr>            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My Apis are as follows:

```
AUDIT
[
    {
    "audit_id": "1",
    "audit_date_time": "2016-01-28 12:46:20",
    "audit_user_fk": "97"
    }
]

USER
[
    {
    "user_id": "97",
    "user_full_name": "Mr.User",        
    }
]
```

Controller, which is working fine GETting the data from each API:

```
app.controller('auditControl', ['$scope','auditService', 'userService', function ($scope, auditService, userService) {  
    var auditLogs = auditService.query(function () {
        $scope.audit.data = auditLogs;
    });
    var user = userService.query(function () {
        $scope.auditUser = user;
    });        
}]);
```

So my main issue i'm having is getting the user name in the table instead of the foreign key value.  I've stripped out a lot of this just so we can focus on the main problem.  Getting the user name from the user API, based on the FK in the Audit API and repeated based on the items in the Audit API.

Any help greatly appreciated and apologies for the noob question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom filter.

```
app.filter("lookupUser", function() {
    function lookup (idNum, userList) {
        var userName = "UNKNOWN";
        angular.forEach(userList, function(user) {
            if ( user.user_id == idNum ) {
                 userName = user.user_full_name;
            };
        });
        return userName;
    };
    return lookup;
});
```

Then in your template:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="audit in audit.data>
        <td>{{audit.audit_date_time}}</td>
        <td>{{audit.audit_user_fk | lookupUser : auditUser }}</td>             
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

Controller:

```
app.controller('auditControl', ['$scope','auditService', 'userService', function ($scope, auditService, userService) {  
var auditLogs = auditService.query(function () {
    $scope.audit.data = auditLogs;
});
var user = userService.query(function () {
    $scope.auditUser = user;
});
$scope.getUserName = function (id) {
  var result = $scope.users.filter(function( user ) {
    return user.user_id == id;
  });
  if (angular.isDefined(result) && result.length > 0) {
    return result[0].user_full_name;
  } else {
    return "--";
  }
}
}]);
```

HTML

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>                
        <th>
            Date/Time
        </th>
        <th>
            User
        </th>                
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>           
    <tr ng-repeat="audit in audit.data">
        <td>{{audit.audit_date_time}}</td>
        <td>**{{getUserName(audit.audit_user_fk)}}**</td>   **<--I need the name not the ID here**             
    </tr>            
</tbody>
</table>
```

**I don't know where the users array are, so I called $scope.users.**

Comment: This works Miguel, Thanks.  I'm going to work with the filter option below as it seems a bit more flexible and reusable but, really, thanks for that.  It will come in useful.